# Subset data frame within a for loop

Tags: r, loops, subset

Apologies if this question is repetitive/extremely basic but I couldn't find anything that answered my specific question. I have a data frame with multiple variables that I want to subset based on the information in each column and create new data frames for each variable. Sample data is below.
Data:

```
Column I Want var1 var2 var3
A             NA   NA   Y
B             Y    NA   NA
C             NA   NA   NA
D             Y    Y    NA
E             Y    NA   Y
F             NA   Y    Y 
G             NA   NA   Y
```

In the end I want separate data frames for each column that look as follows:
var1:

```
Column I Want
B
D
E
```

var2:

```
Column I Want
D
F
```

var3:

```
Column I Want
A
E
F
G
```

Here is my code:

```
names <- names(data)
for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  assign(names[i], subset(data, names[i] == "Y", select = "Column I Want"))
}
```

This will give me three separate data frames with the column I want, however, there are 0 observations in each data frame. I suspect there is something I'm doing wrong with the section 'names[i] == "Y"' but I can't quite figure it out. Can anyone help with a simple answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `assign` use a `list` instead!

```
# for loop approach
results = list()
for(nm in names(data)[-1]) { # omit the first column
  results[[nm]] = data[data[[nm]] %in% "Y", "Column I want", drop = FALSE]
}

# lapply approach
results = lapply(data[-1], function(col) data[col %in% "Y", "Column I want", drop = FALSE])
```

The `drop = FALSE` arguments makes sure you get 1-column data frames, not vectors, as the result.

As for the issue in your approach, `names[i]` is just a string, so you're testing if, say, `"var2" == "Y"`, which is false.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the lapply approach for its simplicity, and I wrapped the whole thing in list2env() to create the separate data frames (my further analysis requires them to be separate and not part of a list). Here was my final solution: ```list2env(lapply(data[-1], function(col) data[col == "Y", "Column I Want", drop = FALSE]),.GlobalEnv)```

Comment: @Gregor Thomas you have missed a comma before `function`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text =
"Column var1 var2 var3
A             NA   NA   Y
B             Y    NA   NA
C             NA   NA   NA
D             Y    Y    NA
E             Y    NA   Y
F             NA   Y    Y 
G             NA   NA   Y" )

lapply(df[,-1], function(x) df$Column[x=="Y" &!is.na(x)])
$var1
[1] "B" "D" "E"

$var2
[1] "D" "F"

$var3
[1] "A" "E" "F" "G"
```